# fix unsafe variable assignment in case statement

Tags: elixir, unsafe

So I know it aint right to assign a variable inside a case statement, but I can't figure out how to refactor this so that the user gets redirected AND the conn gets assigned correctly:

```
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok,user} ->  conn = put_session(conn, :user, user)
                 redirect conn, to: "/"
  {:error, changeset} -> render(conn,"sign_up.html", changeset: changeset, referral: referral)
end
```

I can't just move the conn out can I? I'm not sure that assigns it right since now I'm assigning it to the whole redirect statement.

```
conn =
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok,user} -> redirect put_session(conn, :user, user), to: "/"
  {:error, changeset} -> render(conn,"sign_up.html", changeset: changeset, referral: referral)
end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redirect` and `render` both return the `conn` so the second version is fine.

If the `case` is the last expression in the controller function, then you might not need to re-assign `conn` at all.

```
conn =
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok,user} -> 
      conn
      |> put_session(conn, :user, user)
      |> redirect(to: "/")

    {:error, changeset} -> 
      conn
      |> render("sign_up.html", changeset: changeset, referral: referral)
  end
```

Comment: BTW, the first one is fine as well.

Comment: depends if conn is used after the case, since it is conditionally rebound in the first case arm.

Comment: It does not matter, it is rebound with put_session, and the returned value is still redirect.

Comment: The concern is that conn is being conditionally rebound inside a case.  This generates a warning and will be an error in future Elixir releases iirc.